# How to draw an interaction plot with confidence intervals?

Tags: r, data-visualization, confidence-interval, interaction

My attempts:

1. I couldn't get confidence intervals in `interaction.plot()`
2. and on the other hand `plotmeans()` from package 'gplot' wouldn't display two graphs. Furthermore, I couldn't impose two `plotmeans()` graphs one on top of the other because by default the axis are different.
3. I had some success using `plotCI()` from package 'gplot'  and superimposing two graphs but still the match of the axis wasn't perfect.

Any advice on how to make an interaction plot with confidence intervals? 
Either by one function, or advice on how to superimpose `plotmeans()` or `plotCI()` graphs.

code sample

```
br=structure(list(tangle = c(140L, 50L, 40L, 140L, 90L, 70L, 110L, 
150L, 150L, 110L, 110L, 50L, 90L, 140L, 110L, 50L, 60L, 40L, 
40L, 130L, 120L, 140L, 70L, 50L, 140L, 120L, 130L, 50L, 40L, 
80L, 140L, 100L, 60L, 70L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 130L, 40L, 130L, 100L, 
70L, 110L, 80L, 120L, 110L, 40L, 100L, 40L, 60L, 120L, 120L, 
70L, 80L, 130L, 60L, 100L, 100L, 60L, 70L, 90L, 100L, 140L, 70L, 
100L, 90L, 130L, 70L, 130L, 40L, 80L, 130L, 150L, 110L, 120L, 
140L, 90L, 60L, 90L, 80L, 120L, 150L, 90L, 150L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 
150L, 80L, 90L, 110L, 150L, 150L, 120L, 80L, 80L), gtangles = c(141L, 
58L, 44L, 154L, 120L, 90L, 128L, 147L, 147L, 120L, 127L, 66L, 
118L, 141L, 111L, 59L, 72L, 45L, 52L, 144L, 139L, 143L, 73L,  
59L, 148L, 141L, 135L, 63L, 51L, 88L, 147L, 110L, 68L, 78L, 63L, 
64L, 70L, 133L, 49L, 129L, 100L, 78L, 128L, 91L, 121L, 109L, 
48L, 113L, 50L, 68L, 135L, 120L, 85L, 97L, 136L, 59L, 112L, 103L, 
62L, 87L, 92L, 116L, 141L, 70L, 121L, 92L, 137L, 85L, 117L, 51L, 
84L, 128L, 162L, 102L, 127L, 151L, 115L, 57L, 93L, 92L, 117L, 
140L, 95L, 159L, 57L, 65L, 130L, 152L, 90L, 117L, 116L, 147L, 
140L, 116L, 98L, 95L), up = c(-1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
-1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 
1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
-1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("tangle", "gtangles", "up"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -96L))

plotmeans2 <- function(br, alph) {
dt=br;   tmp   <- split(br$gtangles, br$tangle);   
means <- sapply(tmp, mean);  stdev <- sqrt(sapply(tmp, var));  
n <- sapply(tmp,length);  
ciw   <- qt(alph, n) * stdev / sqrt(n)
plotCI(x=means, uiw=ciw, col="black", barcol="blue", lwd=1,ylim=c(40,150),  xlim=c(1,12)); 
par(new=TRUE) dt= subset(br,up==1);   
tmp   <- split(dt$gtangles, dt$tangle);  
means <- sapply(tmp, mean);  
stdev <- sqrt(sapply(tmp, var));  
n <- sapply(tmp,length); 
ciw  <- qt(0.95, n) * stdev / sqrt(n)
plotCI(x=means, uiw=ciw, type='l',col="black", barcol="red", lwd=1,ylim=c(40,150), xlim=c(1,12),pch='+');
abline(v=6);abline(h=90);abline(30,10); par(new=TRUE);
dt=subset(br,up==-1);   
tmp <- split(dt$gtangles, dt$tangle);  
means <- sapply(tmp, mean);  
stdev <- sqrt(sapply(tmp, var));  
n <- sapply(tmp,length); 
ciw <- qt(0.95, n) * stdev / sqrt(n)
plotCI(x=means, uiw=ciw, type='l', col="black", barcol="blue",   lwd=1,ylim=c(40,150), xlim=c(1,12),pch='-');abline(v=6);abline(h=90);
abline(30,10);
}

plotmeans2(br,.95)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're willing to use [ggplot](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/), you can try the following code.

**With a continuous predictor**

```
library(ggplot2)
gp <- ggplot(data=br, aes(x=tangle, y=gtangles)) 
gp + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=T) + facet_grid(. ~ up)
```

for a facetted interaction plot

[image]

For a standard interaction plot (like the one produced by `interaction.plot()`), you just have to remove the facetting.

```
gp <- ggplot(data=br, aes(x=tangle, y=gtangles, colour=factor(up))) 
gp + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

**With a discrete predictor**

Using the `ToothGrowth` dataset (see `help(ToothGrowth)`),

```
ToothGrowth$dose.cat <- factor(ToothGrowth$dose, labels=paste("d", 1:3, sep=""))
df <- with(ToothGrowth , aggregate(len, list(supp=supp, dose=dose.cat), mean))
df$se <- with(ToothGrowth , aggregate(len, list(supp=supp, dose=dose.cat), 
              function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(10)))[,3]

opar <- theme_update(panel.grid.major = theme_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),
                     panel.background = theme_rect(colour = "black"))
gp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=dose, y=x, colour=supp, group=supp))
gp + geom_line(aes(linetype=supp), size=.6) + 
     geom_point(aes(shape=supp), size=3) + 
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=x+se, ymin=x-se), width=.1)
theme_set(opar)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. I wanted to ask, is there a way to make vertical confidence intervals at each level of the independent variable? Is there a way to remove the background and revert to 'old style' graph?

Comment: @Adam I updated my response with the case of 2 categorical variables + a continuous response variable --  hope this is what you meant. I also added code to show how to customize `ggplot` theme. Generally, you can say `gp + theme_bw()` to just remove the grey background; here, I also removed the grid.

Answer (score 13):

There's also Fox and Hong's **effects** package in R.  See the J. Stat. Soft. papers [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i15/paper) and [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v32/i01/paper) for examples with confidence intervals and generating R code.

It's not quite as pretty as a ggplot solution, but quite a bit more general, and a lifesaver for moderately complex GLMs.

Comment: (+1) I must admit I prefer this approach :-)

Comment: @chl and/or Conjugate, can you say more about why you prefer this approach?  It would help people like me decide which method to invest time in.

Comment: @MichaelBishop Essentially because it wraps up a lot of tricky things (plotting on link vs. response scale, displaying 95% CI for GLMMM, marginalization against interaction terms, etc.) that would be hard to handle in few R commands (and personally, I very much like `lattice` graphics :)